# broken line out port, jack retasking

Tags: windows-10, audio

My speakers jack is broken. I have 5 more onboard rear jacks on my motherboard (M3N78-VM), including the line in.

I have the VIA HD Audio vanilla Windows drivers. All front panel jacks are already broken too.

How do I play speakers to another jack? I need jack retasking. I am looking for any solution, any driver/software can do this?

Comment: You can edit your question to add this information to make it more clearly part of the question.

Comment: USB to AUX:   https://www.amazon.com/LZYCO-External-connector-Headphone-Microphone/dp/B018YV3ALM/ref=pd_sim_107_1?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B018YV3ALM&pd_rd_r=GHK3GFJRFHVBHP8GRJHX&pd_rd_w=TzOkr&pd_rd_wg=FkOZ5&psc=1&refRID=GHK3GFJRFHVBHP8GRJHX

Comment: looks promising, I have 2 free USB ports

Comment: Many HD sound cards support auto sensing. You can try to plugin the speaker to another output port it might automatically configure the speaker for you.

Comment: Do the speakers not work if plugged into another port?

Answer (score 3):

The microphone jack on your computer is for input, and it is set this way at the hardware level.

The ability to send the desired audio stream out of any given port on your mainboard is entirely dependent on the drivers for that audio device.

Providing the specific mainboard model may allow us to provide a better solution.

If your hardware and drivers do not support sending audio out through any other ports, there are USB audio devices that should work easily.

Answer (score 1):

Is it onboard or soundcard?  Is it a front our rear speaker jack?  Is it 5.1 or just stereo?  If you have 5 more jacks it sounds like your board/card supports 5.1 audio, but from your question it sounds like you were just using stereo.

Do you have a front headphone jack you can use?

If not, I think the cheapest and easiest solution is to just buy an HD soundcard, you can get them pretty cheap these days depending on where you are...

If you give more info, I might be able to be more specific

Comment: This is more of a comment than a real answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try a Virtual Audio Cable driver. I am not sure if it able to do something like that. vb-audio Virtual Audio Cable is one example. Maybe you can reroute the signal going to your broken port to another.